# How do you say "easter egg hunt" in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

I couldn't find anything online about how to say **Easter egg hunt** in Esperanto. I can give it a try, although now I wonder if the word Easter is describing the kind of eggs that will be hunted, or the time of year that an egg hunt will take place.

Paskovo-ĉaso / Paskovo-ĉasado / Paskovo-serĉado

Paska ovo-serĉado

Answer (score 1):

Mi dubas pri "ĉasado." Eventuale "serĉado" aŭ "kaŝludo."

Ankaŭ mi ne konas pretan esprimon (nek sukcesis trovi). Pensu pri neceso kaj sufiĉo kaj la tuta frazo kaj kunteksto.

- Por Pasko ni organizos ov-serĉadon por la infanoj.
- Niaj paskaj tradicioj inkuzivas kaŝludon per koloraj ovoj.
- La Pasko-Leporo kaŝis la ovojn kaj baldaŭ okazos la serĉado.

Comment: Ĉu "ĉasado" temas pri la serĉado kaj mortigado de bestoj?

Comment: Mi ne jxuras ke jes, sed tio ja estas mia impreso. En PIV trovigxas frazoj kiel "cxasado de mono" - sed to sxajnas al mi kiel klara metaforo. La afero kiun vi volas priskribi estas simpla sercxado.

Answer (score 1):

Mi sugestas Pask-ov-serĉadon aŭ ov-serĉadon por Pasko por priskribi la tradicio en Usono.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest ***kaŝludo de ovoj (paskovoj)*** or ***serĉado de ovoj (paskovoj)***. I don't think the word ***ĉaso*** is suitable.